# debugging firefox extension from Add-on Builder

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) to create a Firefox extension but can't seem to debug the app.

I have tried:

```
console.log()
Firebug.Console.log() 
alert()
```

Please help me debug this bad boy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says, you [use `console.log()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/console.html). The messages will appear in the Error Console that you can open via Ctrl-Shift-J shortcut. You can also open it from the Web Developer menu but starting with Firefox 4 it requires setting `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` preference to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in Firebugs console.

Comment: Firebug is meant to debug web pages, it isn't very useful to debug extensions.

Comment: tried to change devtools.errorconsole.enabled but it still gives me errors only on Error console and not web developer. Please help me...